# Filter records from DBGrid using Data control and datasource in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6, controls, dbgrid

i got this problem,
I would like to filter the results of a grid when the user enter information in a textfield.

Actually i have the textfield, the grid (a DBGrid control) and the Data Control, but i don't know how to filter the grid with the textfield inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `RecordSource` property of the DataControl to a query. Something like

```
   MyDataControl.RecordSource="Select * From MyTable Where MyTable.SomeField=" & txtFilter.Text
   MyDataControl.Refresh
   MyDbGrid.Refresh
```

Comment: Doing this give me the error 3011, "Error 3011 Jet Engine cannot find Object"

Comment: @fracedo this error usually means that the SQL statement has a typo: 'MeTable' in stead of 'MyTable' for instance.

Answer (score 0):

use the filter property of your dataset that is bounded to the dbgrid,that will filter the dataset records.....
after applying the filter value dont forget to set the filtered := True.